# override corev15 styles in html master page

Tags: 2013, master-page, cssregistration, style

I am trying to make this master page in SP 2013, I have added this into my html for the master page:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/mysite/templatemo_style.css %&gt;" runat="server" after="corev15.css" />-->
```

There are some styles that are overridden by `corev15.css`, although I made it after `corev15`, I tried to make those styles `!important` in my `.css` file, but that didn't work and still styles from `corev15` are overriding my styles.

Answer (score 1):

CSS has a hierarchy of applying. First CSS from external files, then CSS inside the file and at highest priority the inline CSS. So you could tryout inline or CSS inside the file with the `!important` tag.

Comment: Hi Malin, as I mentioned, I used the !important but that didn't work as well, I made my reference to be After=corev15.css but didn't work too.

Comment: Did you try inline style?

Comment: No :( I still have SharePoint overriding my styles. No one replied here as well..